# How can I verify the type of memory that my freebsd box supports?

Tags: memory, freebsd, pfsense

I have an old pfsense router and want to see what type of memory it supports (e.g. DDR2 240 pin... PC100... DDR... etc).  Is there a command that will show me this?

I know I could just open the box to look but I don't want to introduce downtime unless I have to.

-M

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dmidecode will give you the details of what's currently installed in the box:

```
Handle 0x0015, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0014
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: J1MY
    Bank Locator: CHAN A DIMM 0
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
```